# Reduce filesize of a scanned PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I've got a PDF of a scanned document that's around 20MB and I need to drastically reduce the filesize to be able to email it.  I've tried

```
gs -sDevice=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

but `output.pdf` isn't created.  Instead, I get an X Viewer for Ghostscript briefly.  Where am I going wrong?